# Cookie information popup maker - how not to send cookies after a refusal by the user?

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies

I am using cookie-script.com to create my cookie information popup. If the user clicks on "I disagree" cookie-script sends a cookie with "reject" value. How can I intercept that value so as not to send my cookies to the user? In pseudocode:

```
if $cookie_value == reject {
  //don't send cookies
} else {
  //sends cookies
}
```

Comment: Unlike what most people think, you don't actually require permission for pure functional cookies. Like session cookies for example. You're only required to inform the user about them. It's their own responsibility to delete those if they don't want them. So setting a cookie that blocks all other cookies is purely a functional cookie. Nothing to worrie about.

Comment: I created a cookie to remember the choice of the language requested by the user. Can I define it as functional cookie or do I have to block it if the user refuses cookies?

Comment: Pure functional cookies are cookies that you require for the correct functionality of your website. Like remembering accounts or language of choice yes. All other cookies, like tracking cookies for example, require user permission. You are still obligated to inform the user about functional cookies though! So make sure to put that in your privacy policy!

Comment: All right. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the cookie if the cookie is reject.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['reject'])) {
  //delete the cookie
   setcookie('reject', '', time()-3600);
} else {
  //sends cookies
}
```

Comment: If the "reject" value comes from a third-party cookie, how can I get the value?

Comment: Is `reject` the name of your cookie or value?

Comment: reject is the name of value

Comment: @entoni Let me know you want to delete cookie in JavaScript or in PHP?

Comment: I would like to delete cookies in php